# Compute sum of unique values in Numpy Array by indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

I have a task to compute sum efficiently and beautifully.
I have two array

```
dst = [[1 2 3 4 5]
       [2 3 4 5 6]
       [1 1 2 2 3]
       [7 8 9 9 3]]
```

and

```
    ids = [[1 1 2 1 3]
           [2 2 1 1 3]
           [3 3 2 1 1]
           [2 2 1 3 3]
           [1 2 3 2 1]]
```

For each row in dst I need to compute sum for unique elements in ids and return max of sum and number of index.

```
Example for first row: I have 3 unique number in ids in first row [1,2,3].
indices for 1 = [0,1,3]  for 2 = [2] for 3 = [4] 

For 1: sum is sum of dst[0][0] + dst[0][1] + dst[0][3] = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7. 
For 2: sum is dst[0][2] = 3 
For 3: sum is dst[0][4] = 5. 
max(sum) = 7
number = 3

Total: [3,7] - for first row
```

I have no idea how to do it with using of Numpy function efficiently and easy. I did it with classic python, but that solution works too slow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in your example `ids` is bigger than `dst`. If it is not an error, I have not understood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the unique indices like this:

```
indices = [np.unique(row) for row in ids]
```

and then calculate the sums:

```
sums = [np.sum(dst[i][indices[i]]) for i in range(len(dst))]
```

Comment: I forgot to note: I can't use loops

Comment: So you mean that list comprehensions count as loops?